# Load a JSON file without server

Tags: javascript, html, offline

I have a big json file (+-10mb). I want to load in this json file (myjson.json) in a Javascript function located in a HTML webpage. I found a lot of answers on google that say things like "rename to myjson.js" and add `var data = " yourjson"` and in your html file include myjson.js and acces the variable data. This is not what I want. I want to load in the JSON file without renaming/altering it and without a webserver (No AJAX).

Can anyone help me?

```
  $.getJSON('myjson.json', function(myjson) {...}
```

Will not work.

Including css and js functions is so easy why is it so impossible to access a locally stored json file without a webserver?

Edit: json file first lines

```
[{"participants": ["a", "b"], "conversation": [{"sender": "b", "created_at": "2019-09-23T22:04:42.083698+00:00", "text": "xxx"},
```

Edit: adding my js for clarification

Edit: **Can't because I'm on mobile and code formatting doesn't work here**

Comment: Where do you intend to load the file _from_ if there's no server?

Comment: So, you don't want to do any of the things that will work; you only want to do the things that won't work. And you want our help making the things that won't work work. Do I have that right?

Comment: @Flimzy the same way a css file is loaded in. Isn't that possible? A local css file doesn't need a server, so why would a local json file need one?

Comment: Can you update with full code along with a the first 3 lines of json data, need to validate the json to debug (make sure it has the opening and closing [ ] array brackets if thats even present) ?

Comment: CSS files are also loaded from a server. If you're loading it locally, then it's treating your local disk/system as a server. A "server" is any computer system that serves files. When loading locally, that means your local system.

Comment: Well, how would I do this with a json? I can load my css files fine without setting up a server and just the device treating my HDD as a server. I want the same, but wild a json, and no aditional setup. Just like including a css file

Comment: It's really not a duplicate of the other questions asking why XHR doesn't work.  This question is a bit different... asking about ways to make it work.  (Not strictly XHR.)

Comment: Can't be done for security reasons. (Since data read into JavaScript could be sensitive, and it would be awful if an HTML document attached to an email was double-clicked and then ran some JS to raid the user's hard disk for secrets to send back to the person who sent the email)

Comment: XHR/Fetch are the *only* ways to load JSON into a document in the first place. Any answer specific to them is thus general to all means to load JSON into a document. (And XHR and Fetch apply the same security restrictions). So it **is** still a duplicate.

Comment: @Quentin On Stack Overflow, it doesn't matter of the answers are the same, it matters that the questions are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, both XHR and the Fetch API are inextricably tied to HTTP, and cannot be used to load a resource from a relative path unless an HTTP server is involved.  If you're loading your page via a `file:` URL, you won't be able to use XHR or Fetch to get that data.

There are only two methods available to you:

- Switch to JavaScript instead of regular JSON and use a `<script>` tag (as previously suggested to you in another answer)
- Allow the user to drag/drop the JSON file (or use `<input type="file">`) to get a File reference that you can then load.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for FileReader: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

If you have it working, take a look at JSON.parse(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse